# can we do binary search to solve quadratic equation?

Tags: binary-search

Suppose i have a quadratic equation like this, `2x^2 - 4x - 5 = 0`, the solution here is x1=2.87 and x2=-0.87. I tried this python snippet to find the non-negative solution(2.87) by setting range 0 to 1000 and it worked but how to find the negative one too?. I tried the range -1000 to 0, but no luck!

```
def solve():
    low, high=0,1000 
    while (high-low)>10e-5:
        x = (low+high)/2 
        fx = 2*(x**2)-4*x-5
        if fx>0:
            high=x
        else:
            low=x

    return low

print(solve())
```

Or I am doing this whole thing wrong? ***What is the strategy to work with negative ranges and floating numbers in binary search?***

Comment: I'm a bit confused. The equation $ax^2+bx+c=0$ has solutions $(-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4ac})/2a$. Why not use that?

Comment: yeah, I am aware of that! but the point is to explore some non-trivial use cases of binary search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider the value of `fx` on line 6.

```
def solve():
    low, high=-1000,0
    while (high-low)>10e-5:
        x = (low+high)/2 
        fx = 2*(x**2)-4*x-5
        if fx<0:
            high=x
        else:
            low=x

    return low

print(solve())
```

or

```
def solve():
    low, high=-1000,0
    while (high-low)>10e-5:
        x = (low+high)/2 
        fx = 2*(x**2)-4*x-5
        if fx>0:
            low=x
        else:
            high=x

    return low

print(solve())
```

Comment: Ohh! i forgot to change the < to >. Thanks mate! But is there any way to find x1 and x2 in one go? giving range like -1000 to +1000? or do we have to do two search? one in positive and one negative!

Comment: @AminAhmed Must 2 search. `2x^2 - 8x + 1 = 0` has roots 0.87 and 3.87 (both positive)